# Notepad++ Won't Let Me Comment PHP code?

Tags: php

This sounds like a weird question to ask but I am working on a Wordpress blog and I'm editing some PHP codes and instead of deleting it I normally comment out some codes I may use later. But this time, when I try to use the # and // it's still reading the code and it reads those symbols as texts instead. Is this a bug? Or am I missing something, never had this problem before.

```
<?php get_template_part( 'sections/content', 'page' ); ?>
```

This piece of code really don't want to be commented out. Its just really frustrating.

Comment: Where are you putting the characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to comment it with `/**/`
so eg:

```
<?php /* get_template_part( 'sections/content', 'page' ); */ ?>
```

when you use `//`, you comment out `?>`

```
<?php // get_template_part( 'sections/content', 'page' );  ?>
```

so when you want use `//` then you need to add a linebreak

```
<?php // get_template_part( 'sections/content', 'page' );  
?>
```

see [comment syntax php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, there was a bunch of nested PHP codes and I realized I was commenting outside its opening PHP tag.

```
//<?php get_template_part( 'sections/content', 'page' ); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php //get_template_part( 'sections/content', 'page' ); ?>
```